# How to replace relative paths with absolute paths using Twig

Tags: php, html, twig

I am trying to have Twig compile a template and replace all relative paths with absolute paths.

Here is my structure:

```
Source Directory Structure:
myFolder/
    content.txt
    image.png

Output Directory Structure:
index.html
myFolder/
    content.html
    image.png
```

The `content.txt` file contains this:

```
Hello {{ twigvar }}
<img src="image.png" />
```

The `content.html` file contains, after going through Twig:

```
Hello varvalue
<img src="image.png" />
```

I have a PHP application that takes the content from the source `myFolder`, passes the `content.txt` through a Twig template and writes the output HTML into `myFolder/content.html` in the output directory. The script also copies the image to the output directory. When I view the `content.html` page in the browser, the image shows up perfectly, as you would expect.

Everything works fine up until this point as all I've really done is compile a template and view the output.

The question is, how can I also show the HTML output on `index.html`? Since the image path is relative, `index.html` does not show the image.

I want to have Twig replace all relative paths with absolute ones so the output of `content.html` would be like this:

```
Hello varvalue
<img src="http://localhost/mywebsite/myFolder/image.png" />
```

I will know the `http://localhost/mywebsite/myFolder/` string when I am calling the `render` function. I must use relative paths in my source file as the output folder can be different based on site configuration. I also cannot use any template variables in my source content file as the file is written in markdown and compiled to HTML.